# page not rendering properly angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to Angular JS & am learning it for some academic requirements. The issue is that I have a login page, through which three types of users can sign in. Upon signing in, it is redirected correctly as per conditions, but the landing page is not being rendered properly. If i place the whole code of this landing page in  "index.html", the page gets rendered perfectly.There are li tags associated with ul tags which act as a sub menu upon click event on li items. These work perfectly when placed in index.html, but not working when loaded inside the ui-view using state transitions.I am using "state" to change between sections. No errors are being logged and I can't find out why. I hope I have included the necessary code.If the question is not clear, I can provide the entire code.

Please Help.

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Authentication', []);

//angular.module('Home', []);

angular.module('Registration', []);

angular.module('Dental', ['ui.router','Authentication','Registration'])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

       $stateProvider
        // State - User Login
            .state('login', {
            url: "/login",
            templateUrl: "app/authentication/views/login.html",
            controller: "AuthenticationController"
        })

        // State - Admin Landing Page
        .state('admin', {
        //abstract: true,
        url: "/admin",
        templateUrl: "app/admin/home/views/admin_main.html",
        controller: "RegistrationController"
      })

      // State - Admin Sub Pages - Registration Page
      .state('register', {
        parent: 'admin',
        url:'/register',
        views: {
          'admin@admin' : {
              templateUrl: "app/admin/settings/views/clinicDetail.html",
          }
        },
        controller: "RegistrationController"
      })

      // State - Admin Sub Pages - Personal Details Page
      .state('register.personal', {
        parent: 'register',
        url:'/personal-details',
        views : {
          'registration' : {
            templateUrl : 'app/admin/registration/views/personalDetails.html'
          }
        }
      })
}])
```

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="Dental">
<head>
  <!---   Style Sheets   --->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/custom.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/animate.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/waves.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/layout.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/component.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/plugins.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/common-styles.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/pages.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/responsive.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/matmix-iconfont.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,400italic,500,500italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="app/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ui-view>
    <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8">
        <h3> Clinic Management System </h3>
        <a ui-sref="login"> <button class="btn btn-success"> Start </button> </a>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <script src="app/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="app/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="app/js/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app/js/jRespond.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app/js/nav-accordion.js"></script>
  <script src="app/js/hoverintent.js"></script>
  <script src="app/js/waves.js"></script>
  <script src="app/js/switchery.js"></script>
  <script src="app/js/jquery.loadmask.js"></script>
  <script src="app/js/icheck.js"></script>
  <script src="app/js/select2.js"></script>
  <script src="app/js/bootbox.js"></script>
  <script src="app/js/animation.js"></script>
  <script src="app/js/colorpicker.js"></script>
  <script src="app/js/sweetalert.js"></script>
  <script src="app/js/moment.js"></script>
  <script src="app/js/fullcalender.js"></script>
  <script src="app/js/layout.init.js"></script>
  <script src="app/js/matmix.init.js"></script>
  <!---   Controllers   --->
  <script src="app/authentication/authenticationController.js"></script>
  <script src="app/authentication/service.js"> </script>
  <script src="app/admin/registration/registrationController.js"></script>
```

***admin_main.html***

```
<div class="left-navigation">
            <ul class="list-accordion">
                <li><a href="#" class="waves-effect"><span class="nav-icon"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></span>
                <span class="nav-label">Home</span> </a>

                </li>
                   <li><a class="waves-effect"><span class="nav-icon"><i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i></span><span class="nav-label">Registration</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a ui-sref="register">Add New Patient</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Show Patients</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="nav-icon"><i class="fa fa-table"></i></span><span class="nav-label">Appointment</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Fix Appointment</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">View Appointment</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Day Sheet</a>
                        </li>
                        <!--<li><a href="stack-tables.html">Stack Tables</a> -->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="nav-icon"><i class="ico-hammer-wrench"></i></span><span class="nav-label">Employee Registration</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Employee Category</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Add New Employee</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">View Employees</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Reports</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Employee Details</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <!--<li><a href="#">Bootstrap Elements</a>
                        </li> -->
                    </ul>
                </li>
               </ul>
               </div>
```

Comment: What I notice is that your <div ui-view> contains some markup. It will get replaced state's template markup. Review if the issue you have is due to that.

Comment: No change, problem still exist. I have no reputation to post images, or else I would have posted one. Some click events are also not working. If I paste the  "admin_main.hmtl" in index.html, it works, other wise the error which I mentioned before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate the div inside your ui-view and create a new html file with the name 'home.html' or any name you like.

home.html:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8">
    <h3> Clinic Management System </h3>
    <a ui-sref="login"> <button class="btn btn-success">Start</button></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

body:

```
<body>
   <div ui-view>
</div>
```

Then add a new state in your stateProvider having a default state:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider.state('home', {
  url: "/home",
  templateUrl: "app/home/views/home.html",
  controller: "HomeController"
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the info. but problem still exist. When I place the content of "admin_main.html"  in any file other than index.html, admin_main is not rendered properly. You can see the  "registration" <li>. Actually when clicking on that link, a sliding drop down should appear. This work if admin_main.html code is placed inside index.html ONLY... In no other pages, it doesn't work. I can't figure out this error. No errors in chrome console too... :( :(